# prevent user from submitting likes or dislikes multiple times

Tags: python, django, jquery, django-sessions

## javascript

```
$('button.like').click(function(){
    $.get($(this).parent().attr('href'),function(data){
        $(this).html(''+data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

## view

```
def like(request):
    if request.is_ajax:
        r = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=1)
        r.food_likes +=1
        r.save()
        return HttpResponse(str(r.food_likes))
    else:
        return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

## html

```
    <a href="/like/">
        <button class="like pull-right btn btn-info text-left pad0  btn-mini mrg-left5 like-food">
            <i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i>&nbsp;`{{rest.food_likes}}`
        </button>
    </a>
```

## doubt

how do i change the javascript using sessions so that even if user reloads the page , then also he should be able to toggle the likes and dislikes , for example for a particular session if the user likes a particular restaurant , then if he refreshes then also he should be prompted to dislike it if he wants to undo his action , please help

Comment: For JS, you can use a cookie. For Python, you can create a session or log the user's IP address.

Comment: Did you know that your `$(this)` within the `get`s function doesn't refer to your desired element?

Comment: yea i would save the desired element into a variable and then i ll use it with in get , but thats not the point , but could u please suggest me some related example , thanks in advance

Comment: I know that's not the main issue, but `this` in the context of `get`'s function doesn't refer to your button element.

Comment: do you require user to login before voting? if not, this can be difficult.

Comment: no i dont require user to login , otherwise i could have user.is_authenticated even in the javascript , thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store data in user's session in django easily,

```
# Returns value of is_user_like key from user's session if it's available, or False
request.session.get('is_user_like', False)
# Sets value of is_user_like in user's session to True
request.session['is_user_like'] = True
```

Change your template to:

```
<a href="/like/">
    <button class="like pull-right btn btn-info text-left pad0  btn-mini mrg-left5 like-food">
        <i class="{% if user_likes %}icon-thumbs-down{% else %}icon-thumbs-up{% endif %}"></i>&nbsp;`{{rest.food_likes}}`
    </button>
</a>
```

And pass the `user_likes = request.session.get('is_user_like', False)` to template renderer.
Also add store to session line to your like view's code (And it's negative to dislike view - if you have any):

```
def like(request):
    if request.is_ajax:
        r = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=1)
        r.food_likes +=1
        r.save()
        request.session['is_user_like'] = True
        return HttpResponse(str(r.food_likes))
    else:
        return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Look at this document to make sure that you had enabled SessionMiddleware in django - It is enabled by default in generated settings file: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: yea i got your point but what if i have multiple similar models on the same page , then how am i supposed to set the session keys ??

Comment: I think you can store an array or a dict in session, so for example your code for like nth restaurant will be `request.session['user_likes'][n] = True`